RabbitMQ server upgrade for abbitmq.client nuget package version 6.8
I have upgraded rabbitmq.client nuget package version from 3.x version to 6.8 version. Currently, my RabbitMQ server version is 3.9. Do I need to upgrade my RabbitMQ server version also?. I want to know what is the compatability version of the rabbitmq server version of the rabbitmq.client nuget package version of 6.8.
